# Updating a sku using rapidflow in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying update the skus for 500 products using rapidflow. How would I go about doing this? What columns are needed for the upload file?

I saw somewhere to put in new_sku but that didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.